# how can I see how many Flexlm licenses are being used in clearcase (script)?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I need to **make a script** in order to better monitor the licenses left for ClearCase.

I am getting the following error.
Is there any command to check how many tokens are being used and how many are free for me to **use in a script**?

```
Could not get a license! Message is:
Licensed number of users already reached
Feature:       ****
License path:  /**/***/****/license.dat
FLEXlm error:  -4,132
For further information, refer to the FLEXlm End User Manual,
available at "www.globetrotter.com".
_____RTDS_EXPORT_OK____
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original command is `clearlicense`.

But if, when typing `clearlicense`, you get "[`Error: No clearlicense information available. Use FLEXlm utilities instead`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266357)", that means that, indeed, you are using Flexlm to manage the token.

In that case, your ClearCase admin must access the Flexlm Admin tool, in order to get a status of the licenses used.
(It should be the IBM Rational License Key Administrator")

You have a fairly comprehensive [FAQ on Flexlm Token management here (word document)](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/ed8cad16-642c-481f-bce3-8530e23a8413/page/f4a97898-618a-4471-a2ac-5117b433e287/attachment/ead4c758-ef25-4a74-852d-2c87107f7b88/media/token_faq.doc).

It confirms:

```
FlexLM Error -4,132 - the feature failed to check out
```

> This error message will occur trying to check out a license when all tokens are in use.

---

[Seth Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719673/seth-robertson) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663987/how-can-i-see-how-many-flexlm-licenses-are-being-used-in-clearcase-script/23664079#comment129735003_23664079):

> To complete the answer, you can use the following command to get the flexlm license information:
>
> ```
> lmutil  lmstat -f -c /path/to/license/file
> ```
>
> which includes active checkouts of licenses.

---

[Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) suggests (in 2022, 8 years later) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663987/how-can-i-see-how-many-flexlm-licenses-are-being-used-in-clearcase-script/23664079#comment130229025_23664079):

> ```
> lmutil lmstat -f ClearCase -c {license port@host} 
> lmutil lmstat -f TLSTOK -c {license port@host}...
> ```
>
> The latter would need to be filtered on lines with "`ClearCase`".
> The feature name is required.

Comment: To complete the answer: you can use the following command to get the flexlm license information: `lmutil  lmstat -f -c /path/to/license/file` which includes active checkouts of licenses.

Comment: @SethRobertson Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Actually, it would lmutil lmstat -f ClearCase -c {license port@host} and lmutil lmstat -f TLSTOK -c {license port@host}... The latter would need to be filtered on lines with "ClearCase"
The feature name is required.

Comment: @BrianCowan Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.